# Cytoscape content style function not working when being generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, closures, iife, cytoscape

I'm using Cytoscape 2.5.0.

Here's the basic working code:

```
var elements = [
                { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n0", type: "foo"}, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
                { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n1", type: "bar"}, position: { x: 200, y: 200 } },
                { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n2", type: "foo"}, position: { x: 300, y: 300 } },
                { group: "nodes", data: { id: "n3", type: "biz"}, position: { x: 400, y: 400 } },
                { group: "edges", data: { id: "e0", source: "n0", target: "n1" } }
            ];

    var style = cytoscape.stylesheet()      
        .selector('node[type = "foo"]').css({
                            'background-color': 'red',
                            'content': function(ele){
                                return "Is a foo: " + ele.data().id;
                            }
                        })
        .selector('node[type = "bar"]').css({
                            'background-color': 'blue',
                            'content':function(ele){
                                return "Is a bar: " + ele.data().id;
                            }
                        })
        .selector('node[type = "biz"]').css({
                            'background-color': 'green',
                            'content': function(ele){
                                return  ele.data().id;
                            }
                        })
        ;           

    var dom = $('#graph');

    var cy = cytoscape({
        container: dom,
        elements: elements, 
        style: style
    });
```

As you can see we have nodes of three different types: `foo`, `bar`, and `biz`.

We've assigned selectors to color them differently, and display a custom label depending on the node type.

This code works fine:

[image]

But now I want to abstract the assignment of styling, to avoid that repeatition of code on assigning the selectors and styling.

To do this, I create a `Config` object.

```
    var Config = function(type, color, message){
        this.color = color;
        this.fn = function(ele){
            var eleMessage = (message)? message + ele.data().id : ele.data().id; 
            return eleMessage;
        };

        this.selector = 'node[type = "' + type + '"]';
    }

    var configs = [
        new Config("foo", "red", "this is foo"),
        new Config("bar", "blue", "this is bar"), 
        new Config("biz", "green")
    ];

    for (var i in configs){
        var config = configs[i];

        style.selector(config.selector)
             .css({'background-color': config.color, 'content': config.fn});
    }
```

The code now stops working. The color styling works fine, but the label function is the same for all of them.

[image]

I thought this might be an issue with Javascript closures, so I wrapped the function in an IIFE, but that doesn't solve it either.

```
var Config = function(type, color, message){
        this.color = color;
        this.fn = (function(message) {return function(ele){
            var eleMessage = (message)? message + ele.data().id : ele.data().id; 
            return eleMessage;
        };})(message);

        this.selector = 'node[type = "' + type + '"]';
    }
```

Any suggestions for solving this?